# URL Routing Works locally but not on hosting server

Tags: url, routes

I asked a question a while back about URL routing and was pointed in the right direction.  I've coded it all up in vb.net and works like a charm locally.  When I upload it to my hosting server, it ceases to work.

For example if you go to: http://www.nightcat-online.com/Blog/2011/11 It takes you to the 404 page (which it shouldn't) and for whatever reason the css is gone.  (If you go to http://www.nightcat-online.com/404.aspx the css shows up fine)

The hosting server is running IIS7.  My web config that I use locally is basically the same as the one I upload, except for the connection string and the compilation debug.